# Geometry nodes, trouble with a median value

Tags: geometry-nodes

I'm working on a specific mesh, and I expect the Y median value to be 5, but the value is 0.
I tried to simplify the problem in another file, but I can't even find how it turned out the way it is..

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [Median](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Median)  divides the *population* of your samples, so that half the samples are on one side of it, and half on the other.

If you wanted the value half way up your shape, that would be something like `(Min + Max) / 2`.

Comment: Your solution works fine! Thank you!

Comment: @User 'Population' just means the total _counted set_ of your points, regardless of their values. They're just dots. The median puts half the dots above it, and half below.

Comment: I used that value pretty often to find the middle of a mesh on the axe and it was all good! I won't do it anymore...

Comment: @User .. when you used it, you were just lucky :) there were the same number of points on each side of the halfway line.

Comment: I think you can also use a single node "multiply add", multiply `range` by $0.5$ and add `min`

Comment: @MarkusvonBroady ... but I would contest.... 'Sometimes clunky is good' . :)

Comment: "Perfect is the enemy of good."